# What does OpenInputDesktop in MSDN documentation stand for exactly?

Tags: c++, desktop, msdn

I was going through the [DesktopDuplication API Sample Code](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Desktop-Duplication-Sample-da4c696a) and there were quite a lot of function which were unclear to me as to what their exact devices and parameters are. One of them is [OpenInputDesktop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684309(v=vs.85).aspx).

Here's the code snippet of how this function is being used in the DesktopDuplication API Sample Code.

```
// Get desktop
    DUPL_RETURN Ret;
    HDESK CurrentDesktop = nullptr;
    CurrentDesktop = OpenInputDesktop(0, FALSE, GENERIC_ALL);
```

So my question is what does Desktop here mean exactly?

If I have a multi-monitor system, primary desktop: 1366X768 and secondary of 1920X1080 then does Desktop mean only the Desktop Area of the primary desktop: 1366X768 or does desktop mean the entire screen region of (1920+1366)3286X1080?

Or do we have an option to choose one of the two above mentioned definitions of desktop in the function-call. However I could not find any parameter to change which would let me do so.

**UPDATE**
I referred to [Window Station and Desktop Creation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687105(v=vs.85).aspx) and also [Desktop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682573(v=vs.85).aspx) and [Window Stations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687096(v=vs.85).aspx) however I did not find a concrete answer to my question yet. [Here in  Desktops](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682573(v=vs.85).aspx) it is mentioned that:

> This active desktop, also known as the input desktop, is the one that is currently visible to the user and that receives user input.

Does that mean the primary monitor? I am still confused between the concepts of desktop and monitor

> By default, there are three desktops in the interactive window station: Default, ScreenSaver, and Winlogon.

This clears the doubt that there is no relation between the desktop and monitor. But still, when multiple monitors are connected what does the desktop area mean? the are of default/screensaver on primary monitor or the combined screen space?

Comment: MSDN itself can help you with that: [About Window Stations and Desktops](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681928(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I read the article you mentioned and also [Window Stations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687096(v=vs.85).aspx) and [Desktops](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682573(v=vs.85).aspx) However I am still not clear about the doubt I raised. @BenVoigt

Comment: Your confusion is caused by using the word "desktop" for what is actually a "display surface".  When you try to understand the Windows API, you need to use its terminology, which is not always equal to common usage by non-programmers.

Comment: In the Windows API, "Desktop" is an object contained with a "Window Station", and which itself is a container for top-level windows (all other windows are indirect descendants).  It doesn't have dimensions, or anything like that.  It just exists inside the window hierarchy.

Comment: @BenVoigt can you explain me a bit more as to how does a desktop or a 'display surface' to be precise relate to a multiple monitor system? Like in [this article about Desktops by MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682573(v=vs.85).aspx) it is mentioned that _there are three desktops in the interactive window station: Default, ScreenSaver, and Winlogon._ So this means that desktop is only related to the primary monitor right? And a different desktop created for the secondary monitor in a multi-monitor system. Or am i getting it all wrong?

Comment: @BenVoigt Can you explain a bit more as to how desktop is related to a multiple monitor system?

Comment: Desktops and Monitors are both related to visibility, but not related to each other.  A window is drawn on a particular monitor if both: (1) The window is contained inside the currently active desktop and (2) the window rectangle overlaps the monitor rectangle.  Therefore, when the active desktop changes (for example, hitting Ctrl+Alt+Del, or using Fast User Switching), the set of windows on all monitors changes simultaneously.

Comment: "desktop area" has nothing to do with a "Desktop object" as used by MSDN

Comment: It is a scope. If you did `EnumWindows`, then it would know you mean the windows from this thread's input desktop. Each thread has an "input desktop", which windows uses to limit APIs to only reach their own stuff, not reach across into some other logon's desktop. You can log on as several different users, at once, and switch among them. You can use them in parallel on a terminal server.

Comment: If you have a handle to another desktop, you can `SetThreadDesktop` any time to make this thread suddenly refer to the other desktop when the APIs need to find objects that live in desktops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer to my question on this link: [Virtual Screen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145136(v=vs.85).aspx).

Where it has been mentioned:

> The bounding rectangle of all the monitors is the virtual screen. The desktop covers the virtual screen instead of a single monitor.

This is what was basically confusing me as to what desktop exactly stands for. Thanks for your help @Ben Voigt

And here on this link: [HMonitor and the Device Context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144968(v=vs.85).aspx) it has been mentioned:

> Each physical display is represented by a monitor handle of type HMONITOR. A physical display has the same HMONITOR as long as it is part of the desktop.

So this clears my concepts about the physical device, virtual screen and how they are related to Monitor and Desktop in MSDN.

Hope this helps someone searching for answers similar to mine.